# Make TeamViewer work before user login

Tags: windows, login, teamviewer

I have setup TeamViewer on my Windows 10 system to be accessible before user login: I have set it up to start with Windows, associated it to my TeamViewer account, granted easy access to myself, set a fixed password, and allowed incoming LAN connections.

However, after reboot, that system does not appear in the list of my online computer and can only be connected to by LAN connection. (You basically connect by IP rather than by TeamViewer ID - which doesn't help me much when I am not in my LAN.)

After login of any user, the systems becomes and remains accessible (visible and connectable, with no interruption of existing connections) until reboot of the machine, even after this user (or all users) logs out - so it seems to be TeamViewer *Service* that, correctly in principle, handles this connection, but fails to connect to the TeamViewer server before I am logged in.

A second system Windows 10 system of mine, on the same network, behaves normally, that is, accepts remote TeamViewer connections before user login. I have no idea whether this is related, but the misbehaving system has been part of a domain for a while, but I have since left that domain and cleaned up group policies as well as I could.

Comment: You could see if you can change the service startup settings. Its probably set to manual, so teamviewer itself can start it. Changing it to automatic could fix it. Another option could be to uninstall TeamViewer, then install it for all users.

Comment: @LPChip I have checked that the service was set to "automatic" - it was. I have also checked that the service logs on with the local "system account" and is "allowed to interact with desktop" (it wasn't before, but I checked it - no chance). I have uninstalled and re-installed TeamViewer - I have not come across any option to install it for all users, I would guess that is the default.

Comment: One problem was that I was behind a proxy server announced via WPAD, and for some reason, this proxy server could not be contacted although everything else in the network could, and although WPAD discovery worked fine before login. I have been switched to a proper internet connection, and everything is working fine now.

Comment: @bers You should make an answer from that last comment :)